# @ViewChild(CdkPortalOutlet) returns undefined in AfterViewInit

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cdk

Trying to query a `ng-template` with `CdkPortalOutlet` is always unsuccessful, and I cant understand why?

```
<ng-template CdkPortalOutlet></ng-template>

@ViewChild(CdkPortalOutlet) test: CdkPortalOutlet;
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-overlays-68dss7)

Comment: This question is unclear to me. What does query mean? What effect are you aiming at? Please use terminology from the docs: https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview#portals

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use `CdkPortalOutlet` directive in `AppComponent` template you have import `PortalModule` in `AppModule`(i.e. NgModule where AppComponent has been declared)

```
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
...

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, PortalModule, OverlayModule ],
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Also the Angular HTML parser is case sensitive so that you need to use it like:

```
<ng-template cdkPortalOutlet></ng-template>
             ^^^
          lower case
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-overlays-qaupdu?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 8):

Since Angular 8 `@ViewChild` requires to give an extra `static` parameter and the documentation is hard to find on what value to set it to. If not set correctly it will result in an `undefined` value when trying to retrieve `CdkPortalOutlet` with `@ViewChild`.

### TLDR

Set `@ViewChild(CdkPortalOutlet, { static: true })` when migrating to Angular 8.

### Extracted comment from Angular code

**How do I choose which `static` flag value to use: `true` or `false`?**

We have always recommended retrieving query results in `ngAfterContentInit` for content queries.
This is because by the time this lifecycle hook runs, change detection has completed for the relevant nodes and we can guarantee that we have collected all the possible query results.

Most applications will want to use `{static: false}` for this reason. This setting will ensure query matches that are dependent on binding resolution (e.g. results inside `*ngIf`s or `*ngFor`s) will be found by the query.
If you need access to a `TemplateRef` in a query to create a view dynamically, you won't be able to do so in `ngAfterContentInit`.
Change detection has already run on that view, so creating a new view with the template will cause an `ExpressionHasChangedAfterChecked` error to be thrown.
In this case, you will want to set the `static` flag to `true` and create your view in `ngOnInit`.
In most other cases, the best practice is to use `{static: false}`.

However, to facilitate the migration to version 8, you may also want to set the `static` flag to `true` if your component code already depends on the query results being available some time **before** `ngAfterContentInit`.
For example, if your component relies on the query results being populated in the `ngOnInit` hook or in `@Input` setters, you will need to either set the flag to `true` or re-work your component to adjust to later timing.

**Note:** Selecting the static option means that query results nested in `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` will not be found by the query.
These results are only retrievable after change detection runs.